# Using Camshift in c#

Tags: c#, opencv, tracking

I am trying to track a face using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)'s [CamShift algorithm](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv-camshift) but the only samples I found were written in C++ or C.

How can I use the CamShift algorithm from OpenCV in C#?

Any C# example using camshift would be helpful.

Comment: First google hit: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/MeanshiftTracking.aspx

Comment: @VVS: I saw that too, but Meanshift is not Camshift.

Comment: Generally you can call C++ code from C#.  If you C++ code is compiled into a native Windows DLL, that is called `interop`.  You can also compile C++ code into C++/CLI, which means it is a .NET DLL that can be called directly from C#.

Comment: Here's another wrapper with samples: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Intel_OpenCV.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I didn't find any direct example there are some alternatives to directly using the C++ DLL from your C# application, as suggested by Eric J.

There's a C# wrapper for openCV, which looks quite active: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

I also found another wrapper with samples: http://codeproject.com/KB/cs/Intel_OpenCV.aspx

It should be quite easy to port an existing C++ sample to C# by using these wrappers.